# How do I make player not faze from platform sides

Tags: python, pygame

I have started this game and I been trying to make it so when the player touch the sides of my block, it wont faze out of it and actually stop, I want it to work like a full normal block that makes you stop when you touch the sides.

https://gyazo.com/272b729154b0790fd3e004c761cdb658

As you can see, every time I touch the sides of my block, it fazes through it, but I don't want it to faze, I want it to actually touch the sides, I know how to make it touch the top of my platform but I don't know how to make it touch the sides and the bottom of my platform. I have tried the code shown bellow but that dose not work.

code I have tried

```
   if event.type == pygame.K_s:
        if keys == pygame.K_a:
             x_change = -7
    if keys == pygame.K_d:
         x_change = 7

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if keys == pygame.K_a or keys == pygame.K_d:
             x_change = 0

    x += x_change
    if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
            x = old_x
```

My full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))

pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs First Game")


# Playerman
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


# Colors for hitbox

white = (255,255,255)

# Drawing Player
playerman = Player(255,255,40,40,white)

#Drawing Platforms
platform1 = Platform(200,470,100,30,white)
platform2 = Platform(400,410,100,30,white)



# List
platforms = [platform1,platform2]




# Windows color
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

# Drawing the player and other stuff to the screen
    playerman.draw()

    for Platform in platforms:
        Platform.draw()


x = 255
y = 255

x_change = 0
y_change = 0
old_x = x
old_y = y

        


fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # lets player move
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a]and playerman.x > playerman.speed:
            playerman.x -= playerman.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_d]and playerman.x < 700 - playerman.height - playerman.speed:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_w]and playerman.y > playerman.speed:
        playerman.y -= playerman.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_s]and playerman.y <500 - playerman.width - playerman.speed:
        playerman.y += playerman.speed


    if event.type == pygame.K_s:
        if keys == pygame.K_a:
             x_change = -7
    if keys == pygame.K_d:
         x_change = 7

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if keys == pygame.K_a or keys == pygame.K_d:
             x_change = 0

    x += x_change
    if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
            x = old_x





    # About isJump
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False

        # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.right

           
                    
            # colliding with floor      
            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

        # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
            playerman.fall = 0

    # Jump Count

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10


    

                

    
    
        




    redrawwindow()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What does "faze" mean?

Answer (score 0):

When I made a platformer, I checked every frame, if the player was colliding with an obstacle.
pseudo code:

```
if player.movement_vel.x>0 and player.collide_obst():
    player.right=player.collide_obst().rect.left
```

This is a bit abstract though.
I just assume, that the player.collide_obst() function returns one obstacle he collides with.
Of course you would have to:
-Make it also work with the player moving left,up and down and I would recommend making it, so the collide_obst() function returns a list you loop through.
A good source for learning stuff like that would be:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qdeb1iinNtk He covers collision in the same way in his video.
I hope I could help you a bit, Lars

Comment: I'm getting this error, I changed you're code a little bit to fit mines and I'm getting this error                                                                                                         playerman.rect.right = playerman.rect.colliderect(platform1.rect.left)
TypeError: Argument must be rect style object

Comment: I think you miss understood me a bit.
you first do the colliderect check and if they collide  you set the the players position

Comment: It should be :
`if playerman.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
        #this is for the case that the player was moving to the right, you also have to
        if playerman.vel.x>0:
             playerman.rect.right=platform.rect.left
`

Comment: Hey man, It's still not working, can you just give me an upgraded version of my code and put your code on it/ just put your code on mines because mines is not working and I feel like I'm doing something wrong but i don't know.